# Почему я получаю System.StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, winforms, stackoverflow

Изучаю работу с `WinForms`. Тот самый случай, когда я знаю как исправить ошибку, но не понимаю почему она возникла. У меня есть 2 формы `RegisterForm` и `LoginForm`. Когда я в классах каждой из них создаю экземпляр противоположной, я получаю `System.StackOverflowException`

Вот код(укороченный, минимальный пример, в котором суть)

`LoginForm`

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
    {

        RegisterForm registerform = new RegisterForm();

        public LoginForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void to_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Hide();
                registerform.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

`RegisterForm`

```
    public partial class RegisterForm : Form
    {
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();

        public RegisterForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       private void to_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Hide();
                loginForm.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

Я это починил путем создания экземплера при клике кнопки.

```
// В начале самого класса объявлено RegisterForm registerform; (Не в конструкторе)
private void to_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            try
            {
                this.Hide();
                registerform = new RegisterForm();
                registerform.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Не знаю насколько это правильно. Мне бы хотелось просто узнать почему я получал `System.StackOverflowException`. И правильный путь решения ошибки, если мой неверный. Возможно стоит создавать эти переменные в конструкторе или загрузчике формы?

Comment: У вас бесконечное взаимное создание объектов двух типов, которые объявлены друг в друге. `LoginForm -> RegisterForm -> LoginForm -> RegisterForm...` и так до `ru.stackoverflow.com` ))

Comment: Спасибо, теперь стало понятнее. Я пытался сэкономить память. Я думал, что каждая форма создает по одному экземпляру и все отлично, а тут нет)

Comment: `this.Hide();` на `this.Close()` замените, чтобы скрытые формы не плодились, переменную объявите локально, а не в полях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина ошибки - бесконечная рекурсия. Формы создают друг друга вызывая конструкторы бесконечно, пока не заканчивается стек. Инициализаторы полей, как вы изначально сделали, выполняются вместе с конструктором класса, то есть равносильно тому, что вы эти `new` указали бы в самом конструкторе.

Форма, это такой объект, который не стоит переиспользовать, если вы с нее ушли. Закончили пользоваться - закрыли `Close()`, снова понадобилась - создали заново `new`, затем показали `Show()`.

На это поведение завязано очень много механик самих винформ. Теоретически сделать форму синглтоном можно, но только это если реально требуется. Например юзер работал с формой и внезапно вы решили его прервать, а потом снова вернуть к рабочей форме ровно в том состоянии в котором она была. Но это редкий, практически исключительный случай. Поэтому не стесняйтесь, создать форму - не тяжелая задача, вам же не нужно тысячи форм в секунду создавать.

Осторожнее с `Hide()`, спрятанная форма продолжает висеть в памяти в рабочем состоянии. Если вы этот же экземпляр формы не вернете на экран или не закроете через `Close()`, приложение так и останется висеть в памяти, если пользователь закроет все окна, потому что по факту часть окон не будет закрыта, а будет просто спрятана.